# How to properly edit a SVG file to make it square and centered?

Tags: svg

I have a collection of logos in SVG format, and most of them are landscape rectangle, of various aspect ratios.
I want to make the logos perfectly square, and if required center the original logo horizontally and vertically in the square.

Here is an example SVG:

```xml
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="53.6" height="48.7" viewBox="0 0 53.6 48.7" xmlns:v="https://vecta.io/nano">
<path d="M53.6 24.3L11.4 0v23.5c0-1.2-.1-1.6-.5-2.1-.5-.5-1-.6-3-.6-1.8 0-2.9.1-3.5.4-.7.4-1 .9-1.1 1.8h2.3c.1-.6.2-.6 1.9-.6 1.4 0 1.6.1 1.6 1.1v.3H9c-.4-.4-.7-.5-1.7-.5-1.7 0-2.3 0-2.9.2-.9.2-1.3.9-1.3 2 0 1.5.6 2 2.7 2 1.5 0 2.1-.1 2.5-.2.4-.2.7-.4.9-.8h.1v.9h2.2v21.4l42.1-24.5zM7 25.9c-1.2 0-1.6-.1-1.6-.7 0-.5.4-.7 1.8-.7 1 0 1.3 0 1.5.1.3.1.4.3.4.5 0 .7-.5.8-2.1.8zm-7-7.6h2.4v9H0z" fill="#9253a0"/>
<path d="M15.4 19.5V21h3.7v1.7h-3.7v1.8c0 .7 0 .8.1.9.1.2.4.3.8.3.5 0 .7-.1.8-.3.1-.1.1-.2.1-.8h2.1c0 1.2-.1 1.6-.5 2-.5.6-1.2.8-2.8.8-1.5 0-2.1-.1-2.5-.6-.3-.3-.5-.7-.5-1.4v-.9-1.8h-1.2V21H13v-1.4h2.4zm6.8 1.5v.9h.1c.4-.8 1.1-1.1 2.4-1.1 1.9 0 2.5.6 2.5 2.5v.4H25c0-.9-.3-1.2-1.2-1.2-.5 0-1 .2-1.2.5s-.3.7-.3 1.6v2.6H20V21h2.2zm13.5.4c.6.5.8 1 .8 2.6 0 1.7-.2 2.3-.7 2.8-.6.5-1.4.6-3.7.6s-3.1-.1-3.7-.6-.7-1.1-.7-2.9c0-1.5.2-2.1.8-2.5s1.5-.6 3.6-.6c2.2 0 3 .2 3.6.6zm-5.6 2.8c0 .8.1 1.1.5 1.3.3.1.8.2 1.6.2 1.8 0 2.1-.2 2.1-1.6 0-.8-.1-1.2-.6-1.3-.3-.1-.8-.2-1.5-.2-1.8 0-2.1.2-2.1 1.6zm9.4-5.8v1.8h-2.3v-1.8h2.3zm0 2.6v6.3h-2.3V21h2.3zm3 4.2c0 .5.5.7 1.9.7 1.5 0 1.9-.1 1.9-.6 0-.3-.2-.4-.5-.5h-3.2c-1.8 0-2.5-.6-2.5-1.9 0-1 .3-1.6 1.1-1.8.5-.2 1.6-.3 3.2-.3 2.1 0 2.9.1 3.4.6.3.3.4.6.5 1.4H46c-.1-.2-.1-.2-.2-.3-.2-.1-.7-.2-1.5-.2-1.5 0-1.9.1-1.9.5 0 .3.2.4.5.4l3.2.1c1.8 0 2.5.5 2.5 2 0 1.8-.8 2.2-4.4 2.2-2.3 0-3-.1-3.6-.6-.4-.3-.5-.8-.5-1.5h2.4z" fill="#fff"/>
</svg>
```

Please note this SVG has a `width`, `height` and `viewBox` in its source, but some only have viewBox, and others only have width/height. I'd like a solution which works in all cases.

I'm currently setting the width and height to `max(width, height)`, and keeping the `viewBox` as it is originally, and that seems to work as needed, but I don't think that is the correct proper solution (using both width/height and viewBox?).

What would be the proper solution to solve this problem?

EDIT:

I've also considered adding a `g` tag and using `transform`, but it didn't seem correct either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your ultimate goal is to display multiple logos on a web page, you should use the `<img>` tag rather than inline svg elements.

This way, you can take advantage of the [`object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) property to center your image.

```
img{
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  object-fit: contain;
  object-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

If you really need to "normalize" your svgs – [`getBBox()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGraphicsElement/getBBox) can help by calculating a "tight" bounding box respecting the actual svg elements's boundaries.

So you could write a javaScript helper function to adjust the `viewBox` according to the actual boundaries and the desired aspect ratio.

```js
adjustViewBoxToSquare(svg, 1)

function adjustViewBoxToSquare(svg, padding=0) {
  let { x, y, width, height } = svg.getBBox();
  let minDim = Math.min(width, height)+padding*2;
  let maxDim = Math.max(width, height)+padding*2;
  let xNew = +(x + width / 2 - maxDim / 2).toFixed(1);
  let yNew = +(y + height / 2 - maxDim / 2).toFixed(1);
  svg.setAttribute("viewBox", [xNew, yNew, maxDim, maxDim].join(" "));
  svg.setAttribute("width", maxDim);
  svg.setAttribute("height", maxDim);
}
```

```css
img,
svg{
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 20em!important;
  height: auto!important;
}


img{
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  object-fit: contain;
  object-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<h3>Original Logo</h3>
<svg id="svgOriginal" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 12.57" width="20" height="12.57"><path class="glyph" d="M3.7 8.84h-3.7v-6.56h.83v5.85h2.87v.71zm2.97.12 0 0q-.59 0-1.1-.3-.52-.3-.83-.87t-.32-1.37l0 0q0-.82.32-1.39.31-.57.83-.87t1.1-.3l0 0q.6 0 1.11.3t.83.87.31 1.39l0 0q0 .8-.31 1.37t-.83.87-1.11.3zm0-.68 0 0q.63 0 1.02-.51t.38-1.35l0 0q0-.84-.38-1.36t-1.02-.52l0 0q-.62 0-1.01.52t-.39 1.36l0 0q0 .83.39 1.35.39.51 1.01.51zm5.17 2.8 0 0q-.89 0-1.45-.34t-.56-.97l0 0q0-.31.19-.59t.52-.51l0 0 0-.04q-.18-.11-.3-.31t-.13-.48l0 0q0-.31.17-.54t.36-.36l0 0v-.04q-.24-.2-.43-.54t-.2-.77l0 0q0-.53.25-.92t.67-.6.91-.21l0 0q.2 0 .38.03t.31.09l0 0h1.69v.63h-1q.17.16.29.43t.11.57l0 0q0 .52-.24.9t-.64.58-.9.21l0 0q-.39 0-.73-.17l0 0q-.13.11-.22.25t-.09.33l0 0q0 .23.19.38t.67.15l0 0h.94q.85 0 1.28.28t.42.88l0 0q0 .45-.3.83t-.85.61-1.31.24zm0-4.33 0 0q.42 0 .73-.32t.3-.84l0 0q0-.53-.3-.83t-.73-.3l0 0q-.43 0-.73.3t-.3.83l0 0q0 .53.31.84.3.32.72.32zm.12 3.76 0 0q.7 0 1.12-.3t.42-.69l0 0q0-.34-.25-.47t-.73-.13l0 0h-.84q-.14 0-.3-.02t-.33-.06l0 0q-.26.19-.38.4-.12.21-.12.42l0 0q0 .39.38.62t1.03.23zm5.17-1.55 0 0q-.59 0-1.1-.3t-.83-.87-.32-1.37l0 0q0-.82.32-1.39t.83-.87q.51-.3 1.1-.3l0 0q.6 0 1.11.3.51.3.83.87t.31 1.39l0 0q0 .8-.31 1.37t-.83.87-1.11.3zm0-.68 0 0q.63 0 1.02-.51t.38-1.35l0 0q0-.84-.38-1.36t-1.02-.52l0 0q-.62 0-1.01.52t-.39 1.36l0 0q0 .83.39 1.35t1.01.51z"/></svg>


<h3>Original Logo – placed as img</h3>
<img src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 20 12.57' width='20' height='12.57'%3E%3Cpath class='glyph' d='M3.7 8.84h-3.7v-6.56h.83v5.85h2.87v.71zm2.97.12 0 0q-.59 0-1.1-.3-.52-.3-.83-.87t-.32-1.37l0 0q0-.82.32-1.39.31-.57.83-.87t1.1-.3l0 0q.6 0 1.11.3t.83.87.31 1.39l0 0q0 .8-.31 1.37t-.83.87-1.11.3zm0-.68 0 0q.63 0 1.02-.51t.38-1.35l0 0q0-.84-.38-1.36t-1.02-.52l0 0q-.62 0-1.01.52t-.39 1.36l0 0q0 .83.39 1.35.39.51 1.01.51zm5.17 2.8 0 0q-.89 0-1.45-.34t-.56-.97l0 0q0-.31.19-.59t.52-.51l0 0 0-.04q-.18-.11-.3-.31t-.13-.48l0 0q0-.31.17-.54t.36-.36l0 0v-.04q-.24-.2-.43-.54t-.2-.77l0 0q0-.53.25-.92t.67-.6.91-.21l0 0q.2 0 .38.03t.31.09l0 0h1.69v.63h-1q.17.16.29.43t.11.57l0 0q0 .52-.24.9t-.64.58-.9.21l0 0q-.39 0-.73-.17l0 0q-.13.11-.22.25t-.09.33l0 0q0 .23.19.38t.67.15l0 0h.94q.85 0 1.28.28t.42.88l0 0q0 .45-.3.83t-.85.61-1.31.24zm0-4.33 0 0q.42 0 .73-.32t.3-.84l0 0q0-.53-.3-.83t-.73-.3l0 0q-.43 0-.73.3t-.3.83l0 0q0 .53.31.84.3.32.72.32zm.12 3.76 0 0q.7 0 1.12-.3t.42-.69l0 0q0-.34-.25-.47t-.73-.13l0 0h-.84q-.14 0-.3-.02t-.33-.06l0 0q-.26.19-.38.4-.12.21-.12.42l0 0q0 .39.38.62t1.03.23zm5.17-1.55 0 0q-.59 0-1.1-.3t-.83-.87-.32-1.37l0 0q0-.82.32-1.39t.83-.87q.51-.3 1.1-.3l0 0q.6 0 1.11.3.51.3.83.87t.31 1.39l0 0q0 .8-.31 1.37t-.83.87-1.11.3zm0-.68 0 0q.63 0 1.02-.51t.38-1.35l0 0q0-.84-.38-1.36t-1.02-.52l0 0q-.62 0-1.01.52t-.39 1.36l0 0q0 .83.39 1.35t1.01.51z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E" alt="">

<h3>Logo – adjusted viewBox via JS</h3>
<svg id="svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 12.57" width="20" height="12.57"><path class="glyph" d="M3.7 8.84h-3.7v-6.56h.83v5.85h2.87v.71zm2.97.12 0 0q-.59 0-1.1-.3-.52-.3-.83-.87t-.32-1.37l0 0q0-.82.32-1.39.31-.57.83-.87t1.1-.3l0 0q.6 0 1.11.3t.83.87.31 1.39l0 0q0 .8-.31 1.37t-.83.87-1.11.3zm0-.68 0 0q.63 0 1.02-.51t.38-1.35l0 0q0-.84-.38-1.36t-1.02-.52l0 0q-.62 0-1.01.52t-.39 1.36l0 0q0 .83.39 1.35.39.51 1.01.51zm5.17 2.8 0 0q-.89 0-1.45-.34t-.56-.97l0 0q0-.31.19-.59t.52-.51l0 0 0-.04q-.18-.11-.3-.31t-.13-.48l0 0q0-.31.17-.54t.36-.36l0 0v-.04q-.24-.2-.43-.54t-.2-.77l0 0q0-.53.25-.92t.67-.6.91-.21l0 0q.2 0 .38.03t.31.09l0 0h1.69v.63h-1q.17.16.29.43t.11.57l0 0q0 .52-.24.9t-.64.58-.9.21l0 0q-.39 0-.73-.17l0 0q-.13.11-.22.25t-.09.33l0 0q0 .23.19.38t.67.15l0 0h.94q.85 0 1.28.28t.42.88l0 0q0 .45-.3.83t-.85.61-1.31.24zm0-4.33 0 0q.42 0 .73-.32t.3-.84l0 0q0-.53-.3-.83t-.73-.3l0 0q-.43 0-.73.3t-.3.83l0 0q0 .53.31.84.3.32.72.32zm.12 3.76 0 0q.7 0 1.12-.3t.42-.69l0 0q0-.34-.25-.47t-.73-.13l0 0h-.84q-.14 0-.3-.02t-.33-.06l0 0q-.26.19-.38.4-.12.21-.12.42l0 0q0 .39.38.62t1.03.23zm5.17-1.55 0 0q-.59 0-1.1-.3t-.83-.87-.32-1.37l0 0q0-.82.32-1.39t.83-.87q.51-.3 1.1-.3l0 0q.6 0 1.11.3.51.3.83.87t.31 1.39l0 0q0 .8-.31 1.37t-.83.87-1.11.3zm0-.68 0 0q.63 0 1.02-.51t.38-1.35l0 0q0-.84-.38-1.36t-1.02-.52l0 0q-.62 0-1.01.52t-.39 1.36l0 0q0 .83.39 1.35t1.01.51z"/></svg>
```

However, I highly recommend to embed/place your logos as `<img>` elements because:

- they won't unnecessarily blow up the current DOM tree – improves rendering performance
- you could still display logos in their native aspect ratio
- quite likely inlined svg logos will introduce **class or ID conflicts** – breaking the desired display (e.g. caused by style sheets within the svg or clip-path, mask or gradient references)